# ¿Cómo descomprimir un .zip desde linea de comando windows?

Tags: cmd, winrar

Estoy tratando de descomprimir un archivo .zip por consola pero siempre me sale el mensaje de "No files to extract", esto es lo que pongo en:

```
C:\Users\Administrador>"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\unrar.exe" x -r C:\Users\A
dministrador\Downloads\Formato IV 05.09.18-900.zip C:\Users\Administrador\Downlo
ads\
```

Que es lo que falta o esta mal?
Yo se que el archivo esta en la carpeta que especifico y que contiene un archivo.

Comment: Mhmm, has comprobado que el archivo existe y realmente tiene contenido comprimido? Puedes probar con el comando Expand-Archive "<PathToZIPFile>" "<FolderWhereToExtract>" (https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/71z96c/unzip_from_command_line/)

Comment: También puede ser que una ruta con espacios siempre debe llevar comillas. Prueba con "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinRAR\unrar.exe" x -r "C:\Users\A
dministrador\Downloads\Formato IV 05.09.18-900.zip" "C:\Users\Administrador\Downloads\"

Comment: quieres descomprimirlo usando winrar o zip?